# HTML/CSS - Image won't go to the middle, I've tried everything(I suspect it might be some whitepsace between)

Tags: html, css, layout, center

I'm currently making a website using HTML and CSS. It was rolling on pretty well but then I got this problem. I can't seem to center an image correctly. Nothing happens.
I've tried `<center>` I've tried `display: block;` I've tried: `float: left;`
And I've tried margin and padding and everything I can come up with!
Still, nothing happens...

Here's a picture of it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgMyG.png
The "bulldog" and the speech bubble is what I want to center.

Ooh, and btw. Here's the code for it.

```
    <div id="top" stlye="text-align: center;">
    <table style="margin-bottom: -2%;">
        <tr>
            <td><img src="text_0.png" width="50%" height="20%" class="img" style="margin-left: 2%; float: left;" href="index.php" /></td>
            <td><img src="logo2.png" href="index.php" class="img" style="margin: 0 auto; display: block; float:left;" width="25%" height="100%" /></td>
            <td><img src="Bubble_0.png" width="25%" height="60%" class="img" style="margin: 0 auto; float: left;" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Update:** I got it to look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSC6s.png

Comment: Represent your problem with a http://jsfiddle.net so that we can solve it easier.

Comment: Good idea! I'll try that.

Comment: `<center>` is ancient. [Don't use it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center). *"This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time."*.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid too. For instance, `</div>` appears halfway your table after closing a cell, while it was opened inside an earlier cell. That could well mess up your table. Maybe it's not the problem, but it could be. Making sure your HTML is valid is the first step in debugging an issue like this. There is [this validator](https://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: What? No, it must look like it because I had several div's.

Comment: I'm not kidding. The Stack Snippets highlighter showed this right away when I was about to add an answer. :) Cells two and three together are somehow 'merged' with a single div.

Comment: It's invalid no matter what it must look like.

Comment: I removed the unecesarry divs. Now what?

Comment: I don't see any difference in your answer or the fiddle, but anyway it's well worth trying to fix the issue yourself after making the document valid. It might be that the things you've tried before will work now.

Comment: Isn't it valid now then? I'll update the code.

Answer (score 0):

it's your table element and the spacing between the td elements that are causing the large rift between the elements not the images themselves. Make them their own elements (w/o the table) and style from there.

you'll want to use float and sizing to fix this to properly align the elements.

set the div for abuno text (text_0.png) as width: 50% and float it left
assuming that the dog is logo2.png and bubble.png is what you want to center
float those as left, both at a width of 25% and they should layer properly beside each other.

the styling for margins you've currently got on are unnecessary.

HTML

```
<div>
        <img src="./1.jpg" class="img1" href="index.php" />
        <img src="./2.jpg" class="img2" />
        <img src="./3.jpg" class="img3" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.img1{
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
}
.img2{
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
}
.img3{
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
}
```

Comment: Nope, still won't even move a pixel.

Comment: Oooh! Wow, is it you? Cashmanwhat? Youtuber?!?! GHA! In that case, thank you really much for making the PHP login tutorial. I actually managed to make a registering system of it and all!

Comment: i've updated my answer and yes, it is me. LOL. sweet. glad I could help with the login tuts. :)

Comment: Could you try editing the jsfiddle to find a solution? Then send it to me so I can compare it easily. (Also some explanation with be good in that case.)

Comment: did you try my updated answer? i've got it on my screen currently and it works.

Comment: ooh. Well... Too late.... I removed it all I made it again. Now it works ;) Thanks anyways. I actually used some of your method when I remade it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table style="margin-bottom: -2%; 
    background-image: url(logo2.png); 
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;">
```

You could also place your image as a background, and make it centered easily.